# Akeneo 2.2.8 : How can I get the original attribute data in the akeneo.storage.pre_save event?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, akeneo

I'm using Akeneo 2.2.8 and I'm trying to use the `akeneo.storage.pre_save`-event to compare the original product data with the new data provided. I do this by subscribing to the `akeneo.storage.pre_save`-event:

In `event_subscribers.yml`:

```
parameters:
    vendor.bundle.event_subscriber.product_save.class: Vendor\Bundle\CustomBundle\EventSubscriber\ProductSaveSubscriber

services:
    vendor.bundle.event_subscriber.product_save:
        class: '%vendor.bundle.event_subscriber.product_save.class%'
        arguments:
            - '@pim_catalog.repository.product'
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: akeneo.storage.pre_save, method: onPreSave, priority: 255 }
```

In `ProductSaveSubscriber.php`:

```
/**
 * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
{
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function onPreSave(GenericEvent $event)
{
    /** @var Product $subject */
    $subject = $event->getSubject();

    if ($subject instanceof Product) {

        $originalProduct = $this->productRepository->findOneByIdentifier($subject->getIdentifier());

        foreach ($subject->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getReadOnly()) {
                echo "{$attribute->getCode()} : {$subject->getValue($attribute->getCode())}\n";
                echo "{$attribute->getCode()} : {$originalProduct->getValue($attribute->getCode())}\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I run this code, I expect the second `echo`-statement to give the original data (since I've loaded that anew). However, the original product I load from the repository also has the new data.

Another thing to note here is that if I add a `die()`-statement, the data is not stored in the database. So it seems that the repository returns the in-memory model or something like that.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or am I using the wrong approach to compare newly-entered data with already existing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now when I run this code, I expect the second echo-statement to give
>   the original data (since I've loaded that anew). However, the original
>   product I load from the repository also has the new data.

This might be because the object is referenced in doctrine's unit of work. So when you use the repository to fetch what you think is the original object, might actually be the same object you've updated.

> Another thing to note here is that if I add a die()-statement, the
>   data is not stored in the database. So it seems that the repository
>   returns the in-memory model or something like that.

That's because since your subscriber is listening on the PRE_SAVE event, the updated product has not been flushed in the database yet. Saving a product goes this way:

- PRE_SAVE event thrown
- COMMIT / FLUSH
- POST_SAVE event thrown

So if you call die during the PRE_SAVE event, the COMMIT / FLUSH won't be called.

> Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or am I using the wrong
>   approach to compare newly-entered data with already existing data?

I don't know your particular use case but you might want to use a Query function (see https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/2.2/src/Pim/Bundle/CatalogBundle/Doctrine/ORM/Query/FindAttributesForFamily.php). It's purpose is to directly fetch in the database the data you need (it will be the original value since the product hasn't been flushed in DB on PRE_SAVE)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already suspected that it was Doctrines' way of handling entries that the repository did not return the expected result. In the meanwhile I solved my specific use case by using a decorator for the controller (this was the better approach because the event would also be triggered for an import or API update, which was unwanted). I'll keep in mind your suggestion for when I need to query stuff in the future.